# Short Story about Mind uploaded to computer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence, computers, mind-uploading

It is in the format of a chat log. A man's consciousness was uploaded to a computer to save him. Now in the future, they downloaded his mind into a body, but the man gave permission for scientists to copy his consciousness and talk to it through a computer. The scientist on the computer is excited because he finally found a version of the consciousness that is stable and lasts more than a few seconds before going crazy. Does this short story sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Sounds a bit like "[The Tear Problem](http://escapepod.org/2015/03/03/ep484-that-tear-problem/)," first published on EscapePod.org. But it is also ringing vague bells that I read or listened to this story also and was reminded of Roger Zelazny's "Go Starless in the Night".

Comment: Does it have to be a short story? This sounds a great deal like the opening chapter of the novel  "Permutation City." A man uploads his mind in another attempt to get a stable version that does not commit suicide.

Comment: It looks like someone else found your post and used it to ask after it on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/3tholr/tomtshort_story_a_scientist_is_uploading_a/ That said, none of the provided answers look like matches to me.

Comment: Are we looking for the same story? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253554/looking-for-a-short-story-about-a-researcher-that-uploads-his-mind-which-becomes

Answer (score 4):

It does sound familiar. I found a similar story during my search. "[Lena](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/57932409-lena)" by qntm and Sam Hughes, is about a neurology graduate Miguel Álvarez Acevedo whose consciousness and experiments thereof comprise the bulk of the story. The story reads like a summary report on the topic in the style of a Wikipedia entry.

The story is available [here](https://qntm.org/mmacevedo) or archived [here](https://archive.is/qntm.org/mmacevedo).

Comment: Who is the author of this short story? I couldn't see it written clearly on the linked page.

Comment: The work is recorded on Goodreads and cites two authors: qntm, Sam Hughes
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/57932409-lena

Comment: @KelseySorrels Pretty sure Sam Hughes and qntm are the same person

Answer (score 3):

It sounds very similar to "[We Are Legion (We Are Bob)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32109569-we-are-legion-we-are-bob)", which is a story about a guy who gets cryogenically frozen after death. A few hundred years in the future, he's revived (his consciousness is transferred to computers/machines). The doctors there tell him that this process (putting his consciousness into a machine) is dangerous and that some of the people who this happens to go mad/can't handle it. I believe that one of his 'forms' is blown up and the scientist/doctor uses a back-up and puts that into new machines.

Where it strays from your description is that eventually the protagonist is sent out into the solar system on a quest for worlds that can sustain life.

Answer (score 3):

This might be it. It was for me anyway and this question was one of the only things I could find that came even close.

[https://interstice.com/~simon/AfterLife/index.html](https://interstice.com/%7Esimon/AfterLife/index.html)

- not quite a chat log, but is written as a personal log!
- a consciousness is uploaded, though not to save the man, it is simple impatience and desire to push the human boundary I feel.
- somewhere in the future the mind upload becomes embodied again.
- at first the other people on the team talk to the mind upload through text / audio on computers.
- at the start it is mentioned that the host usually dies when trying to map the mind but their company is the first to have done it.

Happy reading!